# In Gimp can I change all black pixels in a picture to blue pixels?

Tags: gimp

Using Gimp can I make all the black pixels with RGB(0,0,0) into blue pixels with RGB(0,0,255)?

Comment: Posting a comment since I don't have enough reputation to post an answer : I made a guide on an image [here](https://i.imgur.com/2ufOhyO.png), using the "mode" setting of layers in order to replace black by another color.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Another way is to use the *Color Exchange* function.

Which is located under **Colors > Map > Color Exchange** and then either select the color from the preview picture using the color picker tool or just define the color to replace and the new color manually.

Here is the [documentation page](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-exchange.html) for that function.

Comment: How do I change *all* colors to a single & specific color?

Comment: Note: The image should be in RGB mode `Image->Mode->RGB`

Comment: Very important to switch the image mode. Also if you have just two colors, switching mode to indexed after the replacement also saves you a lot of bytes.

Answer (score 31):

Replacing a colour can be done like this:

1. Activate the "Select by colour" tool:

   [image]

   - In the tool options, choose a threshold (0 if you want it to be precisely rgb(0,0,0))
2. Click on a black pixel
3. Select your new colour and drag it onto the image